# Don't read String as Regex, read AS IS

Tags: java, regex

Basically I am using the following code

```
message.replaceFirst(cmd, "");
```

This is fine HOWEVER sometimes the value of cmd is "\" and this causes issues as it tries to read this as regex and gives the following error

```
Caused by: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unexpected internal error near index 1
\
^
at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_45]
at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_45]
at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_45]
at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_45]
at java.lang.String.replaceFirst(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_45]
```

Basically I want to know if there is a way to get it to read this AS IS without trying to use it as Regex.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use [Pattern#quote](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29) because `\` is a special character in RegEx.

```
message.replaceFirst(Pattern.quote(cmd), "");
```

You can encounter the same kind of problems in the replacement String as well, in this case use [Matcher#quoteReplacement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 2):

For *as is*, use:

```
String str = Pattern.compile(cmd, Pattern.LITERAL)
                    .matcher(message)
                    .replaceFirst("");
```