# Failing to correctly split strings using Java

Tags: java

I am pulling data from a database and trying to manipulate the resulting strings:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection sqlConn = connectSQL();
        ResultSet rs;
        Statement select;
        try {
            select = sqlConn.createStatement();
            rs = select
                    .executeQuery("SELECT DISTINCT TSK.PointPerson FROM Task AS TSK LEFT JOIN [User] AS USR ON USR.DisplayName = TSK.PointPerson WHERE USR.DisplayName IS NULL AND TSK.PointPerson IS NOT NULL");
            while (rs.next()) {
                String displayName = rs.getString(1);
                System.out.println(displayName);
                if (displayName.contains("(")) {
                    String[] splittedString = displayName.split("(");
                }

            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I am getting an error on this line: `String[] splittedString = displayName.split("(");`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed group near index 1
(
 ^
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.group0(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.String.split(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.String.split(Unknown Source)
    at Main.main(Main.java:21)
```

I don't understand why this is occurring. If I remove the line it works fine. I get results such as:

```
Dipankar XYZ(pradhand)
Rocky XYZ
```

As you can see, some have the '(' and some don't. I tried to accomidate this with my if statement.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20807667/1113392)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`split` uses regular expressions as parameter, and `(` is regex metacharacter which in this case starts [groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). To make it literal you need to escape it for example with `split("\\(")` or `split("[(]")`.

Comment: In general I would recommend the former solution, as it is actually escaping the special character while the latter is a character class generally intended for _multiple_ characters. Both solutions work, though.